# Is "have the medicine" correct?

Tags: word-usage

> You should ***have the medicine*** and take a good rest.

Is the phrase right? Should the sentence be corrected as :

"You should ***take the medicine*** and have a good rest."

Answer (score 1):

Whilst most will agree that this can be interchangeable, I'd have a bit different opinion for the delexical verbs.

I prefer using *have* with **food and drink** and *take* with **rest**. Note that *have* can also go with *rest*. But since your sentence uses both (*have* and *take*), it has become the matter of preferred choice for both the nouns (*medicines* and *rest*).

Having this said,

> You should **have some medicine** and **take rest**.

I knew this as I had learned it on the site of [British Council here.](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/delexical-verbs-have-take-make-and-give)

Comment: I think in AmE while you might *take a break* you usually *have a rest* or *get some rest* but not very often do they *take a rest*

Comment: @Jim I'm a non native speaker and I try to learn English. AmE and BrE will be the further expertise. Also, I always see that there is some way or the other to debate in either of those dialects